# How to fetch ACL permission for a AWS S3 folder to check whether it has permission to write a new file

Tags: ruby, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, permissions, acl

I want to check whether a new file can be written into a S3 folder using [S3::ObjectACL](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdkforruby/api/Aws/S3/ObjectAcl.html)

```
vs3 = AWS::S3.new
obj = s3.buckets["my_bucket"].object["folder1/sub-folder/"]
puts obj.acl.grants
```

But the above code returns

```
Aws::S3::Errors::NoSuchKey (The specified key does not exist.)
```

But the above code works fine for a specific file but not for a folder. How to get it work for a S3 prefix?

Answer (score 1):

Folders do not actually exist in Amazon S3. For example, you could use this [AWS Command-Line Interface (CLI)](http://aws.amazon.com/cli/) command to create an object in a folder that does not exist:

```
aws s3 cp foo.txt s3://my-bucket/unicorn/soup/foo.txt
```

This will cause the `unicorn` and `soup` directories to magically appear, because they do not actually exist. If that object were deleted, those directories would also disappear (because they do not exist!).

Amazon S3 is a flat object storage system. The path of an object is actually stored in the `Key` (filename) of the object. Some API calls help maintain the fiction that directories exist, but they actually do not exist.

Sometimes there is a desire to "create" a directory, such as through the management console. This is done by creating a **zero-length object with the name of the directory**. This does not "create" a directory, it simply causes it to appear as a **common prefix** in certain API calls.

Also, since directories do not exist, **it is not possible to set ACLs on directories**. You cannot control whether somebody can create an object in a directory by setting permissions on a directory (because, yes!, directories do not exist).

If you are wanting to grant *anyone* permission to write to a folder, you can use a **Bucket Policy** that grants access using a specific **prefix**. If you are wishing to grant access to specific IAM Users, then you can attach a policy to the IAM User.